# Is there a seasonality?

Tags: time-series, chi-squared-test, seasonality

I have studied a disease for possible seasonality. Over a ten years period 146 patients admitted with this disease in our hospital. The frequency was as follows: in spring 27 patients, in summer 32, in Fall 42 and in winter 45. Is there any seasonality about this disease?

Considering fall and winter as cold seasons, is there any significant association between occurrence of this disease and cold weather? Could you help me by calculation possible seasonal variation of this disease with χ2-goodness-of-fit test ?

Comment: show the monthly data

Comment: i.e post the actual values

Comment: Do you have exact times, or only counts per month? Show us a plot!  link to the data.

Comment: Seasonality can only be assessed knowing something about year-to-year and month-to-month variation, which we can't see. Therefore people ask for the data in detail.

Comment: In addition to needing the data, if your hypothesis is about temperature, you should use that.